# ansible playbook on multiple servers with different vars

Tags: ansible

I'm running an ansible playbook on a list of hosts with a host file:

```
[consul]
${HOST1} ansible_ssh_host=${HOST1} ansible_ssh_user=devops ansible_ssh_pass=blabla
${HOST2} ansible_ssh_host=${HOST2} ansible_ssh_user=devops ansible_ssh_pass=blabla
.......so on...
```

The thing is that I need to pass a different variable for each host.
I know of the flag `-e` that allows me to send a variable with the `ansible-playbook` command but it's not for each of the hosts.

I'm running the playbook with this:

`ansible-playbook -vvvv site.yml`

How can I pass a different var for each host?

Thanks!

Note: I'm using ansible 1.7.1

Comment: What kind of variable (value) is that? You could build a mapping in a var somewhere, use host_vars (group_vars), query the inventory to discover facts about other hosts, etc.

Comment: Since you specifically say you want to "pass a different variable for each host", you should check out host_vars which are available in your 1.7 version: http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/intro_inventory.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Two ways you should be able to do this:

1) Include the variable in your host file:

```
[consul]
${HOST1} ansible_ssh_host=${HOST1} .... myvar=x
${HOST2} ansible_ssh_host=${HOST2} .... myvar=y
```

2) Or use the include_vars task to load a file based on the host name

```
include_vars: "{{ ansible_ssh_host }}.yml"
```

The second method is good if you have a lot of variables to load for a host.

For more complex cases the lookups module might help:
http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/playbooks_lookups.html